# How to determine if drill is suitable for concrete?

Tags: concrete, drill

I've seen two drills - one 600W the other 700W. Both 0-3000 rpm. But for 600W some guy said it can't make it with concrete, while for 700W reviews say that it does it. Both are hammer drills. I'm not mentioning models as the site isn't about product recommendation and anyway I want to learn how to choose them.

Comment: This is generally **not** a site for product recommendations. But if you provide the two model #s then someone might be able to explain the differences between them.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Reinstate Monica but I said "I'm not mentioning models as the site isn't about product recommendation".

Comment: I know what you said. I am just saying that if you provide 2 specific examples then we can look at them and say "Oh yeah, the 700W has 'xyz feature' that the 500W doesn't, that's what you need to look for" or "No real difference except power, the salesman was just trying to upsell" or possibly something else. Without that, someone (not me - I don't know enough about hammer drills) can give you some general guidelines which *may or may not explain why someone said the 500W wasn't a good choice*.

Comment: Check SiHa's answer below, it may have a better detailed answer than mine.... I believe answered votes can be changed.

Comment: I'll add that so much of this sort of decision depends on how much drilling you plan to do.  If you have just one hole to drill, then even a low-end homeowner-type drill will eventually drill it.  If you have a lot to drill or plan on doing this regularly, get a higher-end or even professional level tool.  You might also consider renting if you just have a project to complete.

Comment: For the average homeowner, this is the kind of thing that you rent.  How often do you plan to use this?

Comment: @JimmyJames 1-3 times, unlikely more, but who knows. There are 27 bucks 700W stuff that reviews tell can drill concrete.

Comment: @RS $27 seems like a really low price.  But it might work 1-3 times.

Comment: @SiHa I didn't say no homeowner should ever buy one.  For the outside of your house alone, the purchase was likely worth it.  But you wouldn't suggest every homeowner buy one would you?  If I'm your neighbor and you trust me with your tools, I'd just borrow yours for a few hours.  The other thing is that typically when you rent one, you don't get something reasonably capable, you get a machine that goes through strong concrete like it's a hot knife through warm butter.

Comment: @SiHa I rented a rotary hammer for $30 US and drilled a few holes in my patio, and few in my foundation to hang a peg board.  I have no need to drill any more holes in concrete for the foreseeable future.  To purchase one of similar quality would be $500-$1000.  There's no question in my mind that I made the right decision.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

More important than the power rating is the *type* of hammer drill.
[This](https://www.familyhandyman.com/tools/drills/drilling-into-concrete-tools-rotary-hammers-and-hammer-drills/) is a very useful link which explains the full difference between a 'Hammer Drill' and a 'Rotary Hammer'.

The former achieves the hammer action by spinning a bumpy disk against the end of the driveshaft of the chuck, which makes is vibrate a bit. These are OK for soft brick, but not much else. If you hit a piece of flint in some concrete, it will just stop, or cause the drill to wander into a softer area.

If you're going to be drilling concrete, you'd be much better off with the latter type. This uses a piston which hammers directly onto the rear of the drill bit, which slides in the chuck (this is also commonly referred to as 'SDS', for the type of chuck).

When comparing this type of drill you will usually find that, as well as power rating, they have the impact energy in kJ (kiloJoules) quoted. Obviously bigger is better. Most can also have the chuck locked so that it can also be used for chiselling, tile removing etc.

IMO - if you are going to be drilling concrete, you would be well advised to pick an SDS drill. You won't regret it.

P.S. As noted in the comments: Both are routinely described as "Hammer Drills". The distinguishing feature of the better type is the SDS chuck.

Comment: I always thought the terms were interchangeable and some were made better than the others, not realizing there a substantial difference in how they are made. (I should have known better, but I never researched it.) I just went with name brands that always performed, after I used other "rotary hammer drills" that did not do what I needed.

Comment: Note that there are as well hammer drills with SDS.

Comment: @glglgl - they are the same thing though, I think. The important feature of the SDS chuck is the fact that the bit slides, and it is hit from the rear, rather than thew whole chuck moving with each impact.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I would go by sorting this out nowadays if I was new to this sort of stuff, is reading reviews.

With my experience I have owned a number of hammer drills which should go through concrete but didn't. I find that these types of tools are investments and quality is key.

To try to answer in my non technical fashion, more wattage, more power to transfer rotational force into impact force. If the impact isn't strong enough, the drill will not go through the toughest concrete, as I have experienced.